# $form.valid() throwing error for date input field: Uncaught Missing number at position 0

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've created a datepicker to select Month and year.
Date format is `M-yy` (e.g. `Jan-2017`) and using jquery.validate.js for form validation

I've following validation attributes on the property in ViewModel

```
[Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? RequestDate { get; set; }
```

HTML for the field is,

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestDate)
```

before ajax form submit, I'm validating the form as mentioned below,

```
if($form.valid()){
//doing some stuff here
}
```

I'm getting following error in browser console

`Uncaught Missing number at position 0`

Now, if I try with different format i.e. for datepicker `dd-M-yy` (i.e. 01-Jan-2017) and for Model `dd-MMM-yyyy` it works perfectly fine

Comment: please provide html which you can use

Comment: @Jay I've updated the question with .cshtml part for that particular field

Comment: can you show how your editorfor is being rendered as html code ?